# Test to determine if universe is infinite or not

Tags: cosmology, universe

Currently it is not known whether the universe is finite or infinite. Is there any test that can be performed (theoretically) to know whether the universe is infinite or not?

I'm still in high school, so it'd be great if the answer provides a more qualitative test rather than a quantitative one,  as I doubt I'll be able to understand the mathematics behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that we can only interact or observe the universe out to a certain distance, it isn't possible to test whether the universe is infinite. Even if it is, the parts of it beyond a certain distance are inaccessible to us through any means, because all information is limited to the speed of light, including the travel of gravitational waves and massless particles; so the only way we'll ever be able to tell whether it is finite is if someday an edge shows up somewhere, in which case we'll know it's not infinite.

Comment: It's not true that the only way we can know whether or not the universe is by finding an edge. There are other ways to test the idea. For example, we may one day find a final model of physics which accurately predict everything we can observe, and this model may also predict a finite/infinite universe.

Comment: Please edit the answer to include @SamuelMontgomery 's comment. I'll accept it then.

Comment: @SamuelMontgomery: your assumption is not safe. We may well find a theory $A$ that matches all experiments and tells us whether the universe is finite or not. That does not mean there isn't another theory $B$ that also matches all experiments but predicts the universe size to be the opposite of what theory $A$ predicts.

Comment: @JohnRennie Does that mean that the only way we can ever know is if we discover an edge?

Comment: @BinaryGeek: yes. Asher's answer is correct. We may one day prove the universe is finite though we're unlikely to find an edge - more likely is that we'd find the universe was topologically closed. We are very unlikely ever to be able to prove the universe is infinite. I don't like saying we'll **never** prove it because *never* is a dangerous word!

Comment: @BinaryGeek:The question of "infinity" is less important than the question of interacting scales. In a plasma of large volume each charged ion will still be isolated by a cloud of electrons that it attracts. The effective interactions are dominated by the resulting Debye length. Particle's that are twenty Debye lengths  from an individual ion will essentially not know anything about its existence. In this sense the absolute dimensions of the plasma are irrelevant. One can make the same argument for boundaries in an infinite universe.

Comment: @CuriousOne Unfortunately, I didn't understand any of that (as I mentioned in the question, I'm still in high school). Could you please rephrase your comment to make it a bit more understandable for me or perhaps post an answer to the question?

Comment: @BinaryGreek: Apologies. The Debye scale in a plasma is basically like the visibility in fog. What's far away in that "fog" is simply not visible. The same is true for the universe as a whole. As humans we live in this particular domain of the visible universe and nothing on the "outside" can get to us. We simply can't look beyond the big bang event horizon. What could be "behind/before it" is not a scientifically testable question. So basically the max. spatial/temporal scale is well defined and walled in with an impenetrable wall. "Infinity" is thereof not even a question that matters.